# QTP 11.0 Doesn't Recognize IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, qtp, hp-uft

My QTP 11.0 was recognizing IE 8 .one week before.Suddenly it stop recognizing.
It showing everything as Winobject. I unchecked enable protected mode also and all possible solution available in Internet.

Please help me if there is any other solution to it.

Comment: You might already be doing it, but just make sure you are opening the browser after you open QTP.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure you are still loading the Web add-in module during startup of QTP/UFT.

IF UFT isn't asking you to double check during startup, then go into Tools > Options > Startup Options and check the box for "Display Add-in Manager on startup".  then click OK, and completely close and restart UFT.  It should ask you to verify your Addins again.  Doublecheck that it is loading "Web", then uncheck the Show on startup box, and click OK.

One other thing to check is to make sure the test itself is using the Web Add-in.  Right click a test in the Solution Explorer, and select Settings.  Ensure the Associated add-ins list includes a checkmark next to "Web".

Note that I'm using 11.53, so could be differences

Answer (score 1):

Always remember to open IE or other applications AFTER you open UFT/QTP first...